# collection_select concat firstname and lastname with same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collection-select

I'm trying to get the firstname(s) and lastname(s) which have the same id.
My Table Schema looks like this:

```
| id | nameable_id | nameable_type | value | type      |
| 1  | 2           | Person        | John  | Firstname |
| 2  | 2           | Person        | Doe   | Lastname  |
```

I want to use a `collection_select` with an expected output:

```
<select name="source[person_id]" id="source_person_id">
<option value="2">John Doe</option></select>`
```

How can I concatenate these values with the same `nameable_id` and order the firstname(s) then the lastname(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
collection_select(:source, :person_id, Source.select("sources.id, GROUP_CONCAT(sources.value separator ' ') as name").group("sources.nameable_type,sources.nameable_id"), :id, :name, prompt: true)
```

Group_concat is for mysql only. If you use others database :

> - PostgreSQL: string_agg(sources.name, ' ')
> - Oracle: listagg(sources.name, ' ')

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works for me with a little modification ;)

``f.collection_select(:person_id, Name.select("names.nameable_id, GROUP_CONCAT(names.value) as name").group("names.nameable_type, names.nameable_id"), :nameable_id, :name, prompt: true``